# How to display formatted month names?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Some languages such as Czech or Slovak alter their spelling based on the context of its usage. However `FormatDateTime` does not have as many options as `SimpleDateFormat` in Java, where you can switch between formatted `MMMM` and standalone form `LLLL` of the month.

I'm using this notation which displays standalone form `30. leden 2019` instead of formatted form `30. ledna 2019`. I suppose there should be some Windows function but I can't find it and I'd like to avoid writing my own library.

```
FormatDateTime('d. mmmm yyyy', Today);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GetDateFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/datetimeapi/nf-datetimeapi-getdateformata)

```
var
  DateStr: array[byte] of Char;

begin
   GetDateFormat(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DATE_LONGDATE, nil, nil, DateStr, 256);
   Writeln(DateStr);
```

For Russian locale this returns correct phrase: 31 январ**я** 2019 г.  (not nominative `январь`)

```
GetDateFormat($405, DATE_LONGDATE, nil, nil, DateStr, 256);
```

For Czech  locale `LCID=$405` it returns `31. ledna 2019`

Answer (score 2):

[`FormatDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) has an overload that takes a [`TFormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings) as input, which has [`ShortMonthNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames) and [`LongMonthNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.ShortMonthNames) members that you can customize as needed (amongst many others). In your example, you want `LongMonthNames`.

You can construct a `TFormatSettings` specifying the desired locale:

```
var
  fmt: TFormatSettings;

fmt := TFormatSettings.Create(...); //specify desired locale...
// customize fmt as needed...
FormatDateTime('d. mmmm yyyy', Today, fmt);
```

If you do not specify any `TFormatSettings` at all, the global [`SysUtils.FormatSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatSettings) variable is used instead, which is initialized at app startup using the default locale of the current user.

Comment: Thanks, I know about this, but if I'm not mistaken, it always loads only a standalone form, and if I want to use a formatted form, I have to create my own and still have no possibility to switch between them other than changing format settings.

Comment: @Triber like I said, you can customize the `TFormatSettings` as desired before passing it to `FormatDateTime()`. So, based on the context in which the returned string will be used, you can preload different month names as needed.

Comment: What if you have `TDate` and `TTime` objects separately, not `TDateTime`? I couldn't find `FormatDate` or `FormatTime` separately. I have these coming separately from (1) TCalendarPicker and (2) TTimePicker.

Comment: @geneb. `TDate`, `TTime`, and `TDateTime` are basically the same type, they can be assigned to each other, the difference between them is just in their semantic usage.  So, you can pass a `TDate` or `TTime` to `FormatDateTime()`, just don't include time format specifiers for `TDate`, or date format specifiers for `TTime`, as you will just get zeros or garbage, depending on the source.

Comment: much appreciated! @RemyLebeau